# Sitecore Media Upload wizard throws "Maximum amount of data upload is NaN undefined" in sitecore 8.1

Tags: media-library

When I try to upload the image in Sitecore media uploader, I am getting the error "Maximum amount of data upload is NaN undefined". I got a resolution to change the **maxRequestLength** property value to **512000**, it was working fine. but i need the **maxrequestlength** value to be **2147483647** for another requirement that breaks the media uploader.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="500000000" enableKernelOutputCache="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

Requesting help.

Comment: Allowing 2147483647 bytes sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. I can't imagine ever needing to store that big of a single file in the media library. I also can't image anyone ever wanting to wait for a 2 GB upload. What type of media are you trying to upload which requires this setting to change?

Comment: @MichaelWest Actually we are not storing such huge files into our media library. One of our api is using a huge size of document upload. But this setting change is required for that api which is running in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value you can pass in `maxRequestLength` property is **2097151**. `HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength` Property is an int data type and the maximum positive value you can assign is **2147483647**, which you want to assign here. but this value is in bytes and `maxRequestLength` property takes **KBytes** size. So you need to convert this value in KB.

2147483647 Bytes = 20,97,151.999023438 KB(floating number) ~= 20,97,151KB